# Java detect and replace linebreaks with \n

Tags: java, json, encode

I get this String from my database:

```
Test Action Item ZusammenführenTest Action Item ZusammenführenTest Action Item ZusammenführenTest Action Item ZusammenführenTest Action Item ZusammenführenTest Action Item Zusammenführen
fsd
fsa
df
asdf
as
dfs
fd
sad
f
sadf
sad
```

Now I need to encode all LineBreaks to \n so I can produce proper JSON objects out of the String because JSON doesn't support linebreaks. How can I detect and replace all LineBreaks in the existing String with \n?

I already tried .replace() and replaceAll(). But I need a way to detect the linebreaks First so I can replace them.

Some additional informations:

After trying out several replace-functions mentioned here the JSON still looks like this:

```
   { "id": 182, 
     "status": "eing", 
     "text": "KORE_AI_6", 
     "beschreibung": "Eins
Zwei
Drei",
         "tags": "KORE" 
       },
```

And it should look like

```
   { "id": 182, 
     "status": "eing", 
     "text": "KORE_AI_6", 
     "beschreibung": "Eins\nZwei\nDrei",
     "tags": "KORE" 
   },
```

Comment: If the line breaks you have are not `\n`, what are they?

Comment: Unfortunately a search for \n dies Not get Any results. I Dont know, this is why i am asking.

Comment: can you also post the code that searches for `\n` ? Is the string in your question the actual string you get from the db or something you see with a viewer ?

Comment: If the lines aren't separated by `\n`, perhaps they are separated by Unicode line separators or paragraph separators.  Try `s.replaceAll("[\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}]|\\r?\\n", "\n")`.

Comment: I know tried your solution VGR, but sadly the JSON object still hast its linebreaks and not /n.

Answer (score 0):

If the `String` you get from the database is called `jsonString` you can use this regex :

```
String result = jsonString.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "\n");
```

This will match the most common line breaks `\r\n` `\n` `\r`. Mind you, this will also replace multiple empty lines with one empty line.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the JSON string still has linebreaks which cause errors in the JSON parser of the client.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for me. Unfortunately it seems like that `.replace()` like stated above in other comments and answers did the job, but the `map.put()` operations after reverted the changes again.

To solve it I used the `StringEscapeUtils` from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` and used the `escapeJson()` method like this:

```
escapeUtils.escapeJson(map.get("BESCHREIBUNG").toString())
```